# how to create a very simple preference activity using android annotations?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm kinda new to android, I've heard about a new interesting project called [androidannotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) tried it and it was great, and didn't effect the app performance as it is a preprocessing lib so you can simply do this:

```js
@EActivity(R.layout.status)
public class StatusActivity extends Activity {  
    @ViewById(R.id.updateButton)
    Button updateButton;

    @ViewById(R.id.statusUpdateContent)
    EditText statusUpdateContent;

    @SystemService
    WindowManager windowManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
          //doSomething
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
         //doSomeStuff
    }

    @Click
    void updateButtonClicked() {
        //doSomething 
    }
}
```

but I've found nothing on how to create perference activity using [androidannotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations), any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward really, AndroidAnnotations has nothing in it to create a preference activity directly. You're asking for something that isn't there. That said, it does have a few annotations to [help with SharedPreferences](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers) in general.